WidgetKit Not running in iOS 14/15 (FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain)
I was adding WidgetExtension target for my old project.
The widget target is running fine in iOS 17, In my case, widget need to support iOS 14 and above, so I updated my widget code to old style, To removing WidgetConfigurationIntent and AppIntentTimelineProvider.
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry()
    }
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> Void) {
        completion(SimpleEntry())
    }
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> Void) {
        completion(Timeline(entries: [SimpleEntry()], policy: .never))
    }
    typealias Entry = SimpleEntry
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date = Date()
}

struct NCWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Time:")
            Text(entry.date, style: .time)
        }
    }
}

struct NCWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "NCWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            NCWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("DisplayName")
        .description("description")
    }
}

In my case, the code was working fine in iOS 17 simulator, But if I try to run in iOS 15, it returns the below error

Error details:
code-SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show Widget 'com.name-pprd.NCWidgetExtension' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x600003570b40 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to show Widget 'com.name-pprd.NCWidgetExtension' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x600003570b40 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}., NSUnderlyingError=0x600003570bd0 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x600003570b40 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}}}
Domain: DTXMessage
Code: 1
User Info: {
DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-07-20 17:30:58 +0000";
}
System Information
macOS Version 14.5 (Build 23F79)
Xcode 15.0.1 (22266) (Build 15A507)
Timestamp: 2024-07-20T23:00:58+05:30

In widget target Minimum target is 14.0
In App target Minimum target is 13.0

If you compile a minimal "hello world" Widget for iOS17, and run it in this environment, does it work? There's been a lot of new features added to widgets, maybe there's something in your code that Xcode didn't catch, that doesn't interoperate with older iOS
